# Vagrant Provision is not working (tried several times already)

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'm having issues running the provision on the LAMP box.

The version of the Vagrant: 1.3.0

I have created a VM and ran Vagrant up. I get a time out error but the VM seems to be up and running (vagrant status shows the status of the VM).

When I tried running the "vagrant provision" I received the following error.

```
$ vagrant provision
[default] Running provisioner: shell...
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
[default] Running: C:/Users/vjay/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20140127-4496-wgoaz8
/bin/bash: /vagrant/shell/os-detect.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /vagrant/shell/os-detect.sh: No such file or directory
cat: /vagrant/shell/self-promotion.txt: No such file or directory
Created directory /.puphpet-stuff
[default] Running provisioner: shell...
[default] Running: C:/Users/vjay/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20140127-4496-1mc5ktv
/bin/bash: /vagrant/shell/os-detect.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /vagrant/shell/os-detect.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /vagrant/shell/os-detect.sh: No such file or directory
[default] Running provisioner: shell...
[default] Running: C:/Users/vjay/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20140127-4496-1beurlg
/bin/bash: /vagrant/shell/os-detect.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /vagrant/shell/os-detect.sh: No such file or directory
Installing git
Finished installing git
cp: Copied Puppetfile
cannot stat `/vagrant/puppet/Puppetfile': No such file or directory
Installing librarian-puppet
Finished installing librarian-puppet
Running initial librarian-puppet
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:770:in `read': No such file or directory - /etc/puppet/Puppetfile (Errno::ENOENT) 
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:770:in `read'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-0.9.10/vendor/librarian/lib/librarian/specfile.rb:14:in `read'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-0.9.10/vendor/librarian/lib/librarian/action/resolve.rb:12:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-0.9.10/vendor/librarian/lib/librarian/cli.rb:161:in `resolve!'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-0.9.10/lib/librarian/puppet/cli.rb:63:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `__send__'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-0.9.10/vendor/librarian/lib/librarian/cli.rb:29:in `bin!'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/librarian-puppet-0.9.10/bin/librarian-puppet:9
from /usr/bin/librarian-puppet:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/librarian-puppet:19
Finished running initial librarian-puppet
[default] Running provisioner: puppet...
Shared folders that Puppet requires are missing on the virtual machine.
This is usually due to configuration changing after already booting the
machine. The fix is to run a `vagrant reload` so that the proper shared
folders will be prepared and mounted on the VM.
```

Just to add on to that, I dug through several blog posts and one of those posts asked to try the command line git utility (because apparently there were issues around CRLF and LF). I deleted everything and tried the command line git but to no avail.

Can someone please help resolve this issue.

Update: Vagrant file attached:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
BOX_NAME = "dct-lamp-local"
RELATIVE = '../..'
ROOT = '/vagrant'

load '../common.include'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

config.vm.synced_folder "#{RELATIVE}/www/", "/var/www/html", id: "apache", :nfs => false, :mount_options => ["uid=510,gid=510"]

config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
virtualbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", BOX_NAME]
virtualbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
virtualbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
virtualbox.customize ["setextradata", :id, "--VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
end

config.vm.box = BOX_NAME
config.vm.hostname = "#{BOX_NAME}.local"

end
```

Comment: By the way, I cannot review the suggested edits. So can someone please review and post this query. Just to clarify this is not done on the server side (I was trying to setup the VM on the Client side)

Comment: Could you add the complete Vagrantfile or maybe a link with all the files? That way I can test it and dig into the problem

Comment: Please find the vagrantfile content attached:

Comment: Hello Cocheese, did you get the vagrant file I attached. Did you manage to see any errors in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should change the ROOT line in the vagrant file to point to the actual location of the vagrant file you got from PuPHPet.

The first error indicates that it is looking for a script in the shell directory under /vagrant, and ROOT is set to /vagrant in your vagrant file.

```
/bin/bash: /vagrant/shell/os-detect.sh: No such file or directory
```